# Как получить список всех полей объекта (включая вложенные) с помощью рефлексии

Tags: java, api, рефлексия

Товарищи, который день ломаю голову как корректней вытащить все поля объекта с помощью рефлексии. Затруднение заключается в том, что я заранее не знаю какой объект ко мне придет но мне нужно получить список всех его полей включая все вложенные объекты и их поля и тд.

Пример:

```
public class House {

private int height;
private String houseName;
private HouseGuard houseGuard;
private Boolean isBad = false;

}
```

У класса HouseGuard тоже может быть в качестве поля другой объект и так несколько раз. Я понимаю, что мне необходимо рекурсивным методом пробежаться по всем полям объекта и если это поле объект, то пробежаться и по нему и тд. Но пока эксперименты заканчивались переполнением стека.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А как насчет того, что в двух классах может быть поле с одинаковым названием?) А если класс наследуется от другого класса (это о `getDeclaredFields`)

Ну а в целом можно заюзать [commons-lang3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3), например:

```
public static List<Field> openCls(Class<?> cls) {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Field field : FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList(cls)) {
        if(ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(field.getType())) {
            fields.add(field);
        }
        else {
            fields.addAll(openCls(field.getType()));
        }
    }

    return fields;
}
```

Comment: Действительно мое решение не идеальное) Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 2):

Решение нашел пока писал вопрос, оставлю его тут:

```
public static Map<String, Object> returnFieldsWithValues(Field[] fields) {

    Map<String, Object> map = null;
    try {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : fields){
            field.setAccessible(true);

            if(!field.getType().isPrimitive() &&
                    !field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("String")&&
                    !field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("Integer")&&
                    !field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("Boolean")&&
                    !field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("Enum")&&
                    !field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("Double")&&
                    !field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("Float")&&
                    !field.getType().getSimpleName().equals("Long")){

                map.putAll(returnFieldsWithValues(field.getType().getDeclaredFields()));

            }else {
                map.put(field.getName(), field.getType().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return map;
}
```

Метод собирает все поля объекта в мапу включая поля полей и тд.

Answer (score 2):

Немного подумав, а также благодаря совету lampa набросал следующий алгоритм который собирает мапу из объектов в качестве ключа и коллекции полей в качестве значения. По идее должно работать при любом кол-ве вложенных объектов.

```
private static Map<Object,List<Field>> openCls(Object targetObject) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Map<Object,List<Field>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(Field field : FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList(targetObject.getClass())) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if(ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(field.getType())) {
            map.put(targetObject,FieldUtils.getAllFieldsList(targetObject.getClass()));
        }
        else {
            map.putAll(openCls(field.get(targetObject)));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

В таком случае мы получаем все объекты (включая вложенные) а также список всех их полей, что позволяет нам доставать значения из них при помощи field.get(Object)

Например ищу поле под названием "level" и получаю его значение

```
Map<Object,List<Field>> map = openCls(house);

    for (Map.Entry<Object,List<Field>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        for(Field field:entry.getValue()){
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if(field.getName().equals("level")){
                Object objectValue = field.get(entry.getKey());
                System.out.println(objectValue.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```